# How to create and manage large XML files in C

Tags: c, libxml2

What is the best library in C to create large XML files. I have to create a XML files with more than 7000 nodes by reading values from a sqlite3 db. I know about libxml2 and also used it but since its a memory based XML parser I'm not sure how well it can manage this huge number of XML nodes. Is there any alternative or any other way to use libxml2 to manage huge XML files?

Comment: 7000 nodes isn't really "huge" in itself.

Comment: If you're going straight from your database format to XML then `printf` is a good option. You don't really need an XML parser to write XML.

Comment: @Mike: I hope that's `printf` combined with something that escapes special XML characters

Comment: @Matti: There are only five characters to escape... You probably don't need a library to take care of that. I can write a function for you in the answer section if you like.

Comment: @Mike: Just saying before we get yet another piece of "XML software" that doesn't produce valid XML.

Answer (score 4):

Use libxml's [xmlWriter](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlwriter.html) streaming API to minimize your memory use.  Rather than building up a tree of nodes in memory, you call functions like [xmlTextWriterStartElement](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlwriter.html#xmlTextWriterStartElement), [xmlTextWriterWriteAttribute](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlwriter.html#xmlTextWriterWriteAttribute), etc. to write your XML directly to a file or other output.

It has similar usage as the "just use printf"-style solutions, with the MAJOR advantage of still using an actual XML library, so it takes care of all the nastiness for you.

You can find an [example usage](http://xmlsoft.org/examples/testWriter.c) on the page of [libxml2 examples](http://xmlsoft.org/examples/index.html).

Comment: This sounds bit easy I'll try this out. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

If speed and memory usage are you biggest concern then the optimal solution is probably using the `stdio.h` functions along with a function to escape the [XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/where-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-xml-document-escape-characters) [entities](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#syntax).

This function should be sufficient for printing an escaped string to a C stream:

```
int xml_puts(const char *string, FILE *stream)
{
    int i = 0, c, status;
    while ((c = string[i++])) {
        switch (c) {
        case '"':
            status = fputs("&quot;", stream);
            break;
        case '\'':
            status = fputs("&apos;", stream);
            break;
        case '<':
            status = fputs("&lt;", stream);
            break;
        case '>':
            status = fputs("&gt;", stream);
            break;
        case '&':
            status = fputs("&amp;", stream);
            break;
        default:
            status = putc(c, stream);
            break;
        }
        if (EOF == status) {
            return -1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The above code can easily be adapted for other uses, e.g. writing to a buffer.

A drawback with this method (as pointed out by @Matti in the comments section) is that you will have to use external tools to do validation on the XML you produce. There are various tools available for XML validation, `xmllint` (released as a part of Libxml2) is one that comes to mind.

Comment: I'd recommend `putc` over `fputc` to prevent function call overhead.